# Matrix inverse and Hermitian transpose

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Could anyone  help me to prove the following the equation?

> $\large ( G_2^H G_2 + K_w^{-1} )^{-1} = Q$
>
> which leads to
>
> $\large K_w = Q - Q G_2^H ( G_2 Q G_2^H - I )^{-1} G_2 Q$

Here $A^H$ is the Hermitian transpose (conjugate transpose) of $A$.

Comment: So, are you trying to prove the second equation from the first?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to prove the second equation from the first equation.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me a simple case of the Woodbury matrix identity:
$$ (A+UCV)^{-1}=A^{-1}-A^{-1}U(C^{-1}+UA^{-1}V)^{-1} VA^{-1}$$
For more details see:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity

Comment: I am trying to prove the second equation. It is not easy to get direct from matrix inversion lamma.

Comment: Ok, I just tried to help you, if you want to do it in another way, never mind.